# parse number string from Angular pipe "number" (l10n)

Tags: angular, localization, angular8

I format numbers with the Angular pipe "number". In order to work with them they have to become float again.
But what is the counterpart to the Angular pipe "number"?

Here is my template code:

```js
<input type="text" [ngModel]="floatValue | number:'3.1-4':'de'" (ngModelChange)="floatValueChange($event)">
```

The event "ngModelChange" unfortunately returns the formatted string.

How can you parse number strings to float in Angular 8?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem here to sum number and a masked/text currency values. I solved creating a Pipe and using it wherever I need it in my system.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
 @Pipe({
     // tslint:disable-next-line:pipe-naming
     name: 'toNumber',
     pure: false }) export class ToNumberPipe implements PipeTransform { 
     public transform(items: any): any {
         if (!items) {
             return 0;
         }
         return parseInt(items, 10);
     } }
```

In the HTML

```
{{ attr.text | toNumber }}
```

Remember to declare this Pipe to be accessed when you need it in the modules.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily convert your string into a number.

```
floatValueChange(floatnumber) {
  console.log('Add 1' + (+floatnumber +1));
}
```

NOTE: JS doesn't have a concept of `float`, `double`, `int`.

Comment: a number string with the plus operator returns NaN

Comment: How does the number string look like? What do you try? `+"12.34"+3` ==> `15.34` this you could easily test on the console. Or you mean `eval('3.1-4')` ?

Comment: l10n number strings: '1,234,56' for EN or '9.876,54' for germany

Comment: the pipe `number` compute the string

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my needs works with [angular-l10n](https://robisim74.github.io/angular-l10n/).

The input element:

```
<input #quantity type="text" (keyup.enter)="updateQuantity(quantity.value)"
             value="{{productQuantity}}" l10nDecimal digits="1.2-5">
```

angular-l10n uses a global `locale` for localization like number format & parse. That's what I wanted in the end.